# How to avoid multiple for loops in this optimization problem

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to find the combination of columns "a" and "b" in table "brand_1" and "brand_2" that
maximize my objective function "obj." How can I accomplish this without writing 4 for-loops?

Here is a simple code to illustrate my question. I also need to **generalize** it so that it works for any number of tables (not just "brand_1" and "brand_2") with each table will always have two columns ("a" and "b"). Thanks so much!

```
brand_1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 3),  b = c(5, 2))
brand_2 <- data.frame(a = c(5, 4),  b = c(2, 1))

num_row <- nrow(brand_1) # where nrow(brand_1) = nrow(brand_2)

all_a1 <- vector()
all_b1 <- vector()
all_a2 <- vector()
all_b2 <- vector()
all_obj <- vector()

for (a1 in 1:num_row) {
  for (b1 in 1:num_row) {
    for (a2 in 1:num_row) {
      for (b2 in 1:num_row) {
        obj <- brand_1[a1, "a"] + brand_1[b1, "b"] + brand_2[a2, "a"] + brand_2[b2, "b"]
        all_a1  <- c(all_a1, brand_1[a1, "a"])
        all_b1  <- c(all_b1, brand_1[b1, "b"])
        all_a2  <- c(all_a2, brand_2[a2, "a"])
        all_b2  <- c(all_b2, brand_2[b2, "b"])
        
        all_obj <- c(all_obj, obj)
      }
    }
  }
}

out <- data.frame(all_a1, all_b1, all_a2, all_b2, all_obj)
```

[image] Here line 9 shows the solution that maximizes "obj".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid`

```
out <- expand.grid(c(brand_1, brand_2))
names(out) <- make.unique(names(out))
out$all_obj <- rowSums(out)
```

-output

```
out
#   a b a.1 b.1 all_obj
#1  1 5   5   2      13
#2  3 5   5   2      15
#3  1 2   5   2      10
#4  3 2   5   2      12
#5  1 5   4   2      12
#6  3 5   4   2      14
#7  1 2   4   2       9
#8  3 2   4   2      11
#9  1 5   5   1      12
#10 3 5   5   1      14
#11 1 2   5   1       9
#12 3 2   5   1      11
#13 1 5   4   1      11
#14 3 5   4   1      13
#15 1 2   4   1       8
#16 3 2   4   1      10
```

---

Or with `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_cols(brand_1, brand_2)  %>%
    complete(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))) %>% 
    mutate(all_obj = rowSums(.))
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun! But how can we make it general (i.e. for brad_1, brand_2, ..., brand_n)?

Comment: @Ketty Sure, we can get all the elements loaded as `mget(ls(pattern = '^brand_\\d+$')) %>% bind_cols %>%  complete(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))) %>% 
    mutate(all_obj = rowSums(.))`

Answer (score 1):

For a general solution with any number of dataframes we can use `ls` to get all the objects with `"brand"` in it, get them in list using `mget`, rename the column names based on there object name and use `crossing` to generate their all possible combinations. Finally, you can use `rowSums` to sum the rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

mget(ls(pattern = 'brand')) %>%
  imap_dfc(~setNames(., paste0(names(.x), sub('.*_', '', .y)))) %>%
  do.call(crossing, .) %>%
  mutate(all_obj = rowSums(.))

#      a1    b1    a2    b2 all_obj
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1     2     4     1       8
# 2     1     2     4     2       9
# 3     1     2     5     1       9
# 4     1     2     5     2      10
# 5     1     5     4     1      11
# 6     1     5     4     2      12
# 7     1     5     5     1      12
# 8     1     5     5     2      13
# 9     3     2     4     1      10
#10     3     2     4     2      11
#11     3     2     5     1      11
#12     3     2     5     2      12
#13     3     5     4     1      13
#14     3     5     4     2      14
#15     3     5     5     1      14
#16     3     5     5     2      15
```